# Return a Value on Two Criteria

Tags: excel

I have a master data spreadsheet and a summary cover.  The master contains a list of names as the rows and dates as the columns.  The data in the cell is sales.

On the summary, I have the names as the rows, then this week and last weeks ending date as columns.  These are calculated using `=TODAY()` and `=TODAY()-7`.

I would like the cover sheet to do some kind of look up to the master data, to look up by name, then return last weeks and this weeks values.  I know these two values would be different formulas.

Is there a lookup that can use the two week formulas to return values from the master data, using the name as well?  I have tried VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP to no avail.

Comment: give us an example and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You just need an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) while providing both the *row_num* and *column_num* parameters with two [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)'s.

[image: INDEX with two MATCH functions]

Note that the column headings in H1:I1 match the row headings in A4:A5. These will be used to match which row to return. Similarly, the names in G2:G3 will be matched against the names in B3:E3.

The [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) formula in H2 (your summary) would be,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$E$5, MATCH(H$1, $A$4:$A$5, 0), MATCH($G2, $B$3:$E$3, 0)), "")
```

Fill both right and down as necessary.

Alternate [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) equivalent for H2:

```
=VLOOKUP(H$1, $A$3:$E$5, MATCH($G2, $A$3:$E$3, 0), FALSE)
```

This time MATCH is used only for the column to return. Fill both right and down.

Alternate [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a) equivalent for H2:

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP($G2, $B$3:$E$5, MATCH(H$1, $A$3:$A$5, 0), FALSE), "")
```

This time MATCH is used only for the row to return. Fill both right and down.

Note that I've used the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) as an error control wrapper for each of these. If the value(s) cannot be located, a zero-length string (e.g. "") is returned rather than an #N/A error.